# i have no idea how to input ordered number inside cell with looping

Tags: php, html, for-loop

please help me i have a problem when i must insert a number in order 1-20 inside 4x5 table, i have tried with "for" method but the result was "1,1;1,2;1,3....;4,5" not "1,2,3,4.....,20".

this is my code:

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <?php for( $i=1; $i<=3; $i++ ): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php for( $j=1; $j<=5; $j++ ): ?>
                <td><?php echo "$i,$j"; ?></td>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

thanks btw

Comment: `for( $i=1; $i<=4; …`, and `($i-1)*5+$j` …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want something like this:

| E | E | E | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |

If that's the case, you need to `loop` differently to account for different rows every 4 elements.

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
 <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) : ?>
     <tr>
         <?php for ($j = 1; $j <= 4; $j++) : ?>
             <td><?php echo (($i*4)+$j); ?></td>
         <?php endfor; ?>
     </tr>
 <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: your logic does [not](https://3v4l.org/UgBrG) yield the expected outcome, have you tested it?

Comment: Thanks for noticing I had edited the second max value of the loop!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a counter, `$count`:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <?php $count=0; for( $i=1; $i<=4; $i++ ): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php for( $j=1; $j<=5; $j++ ): ?>
                <td><?php $count++; echo $count; ?></td>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

note: I have added a fourth row `($i <= 4)`

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/b6tME)

Answer (score 2):

Loop from 1 to 20 and every 4 numbers, add a new row

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <?php for($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++ ): ?>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <?php
            if ($i % 4 == 0)
            {
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, but i got an issue  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "}", expecting "," or ";" in E:\xampp\htdocs\phpdasar\pertemuan3\latihan1.4(modif).php on line 16

Comment: @BarryJr Then you must have done something wrong while integrating this into your code, because on its own, this code works just fine.

Comment: Ok i will try to find it, thanks guys btw